# ffmpeg sws_scale got distorted image from YUV420P to RGB24

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I got distorted image when try to convert YUV420p to RGB24 using 
sws_scale.

Code:

```
ret = avcodec_decode_video2(video_dec_ctx, frame, got_frame, &pkt);
if (ret < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error decoding video frame\n");
    return ret;
}
if (*got_frame) 
{
    printf("video_frame%s n:%d coded_n:%d pts:%s\n",
               cached ? "(cached)" : "",
               video_frame_count++, frame->coded_picture_number,
               "#"/*av_ts2timestr(frame->pts, &video_dec_ctx->time_base)*/);
    /* copy decoded frame to destination buffer:
     * this is required since rawvideo expects non aligned data */
    av_image_copy(video_dst_data, video_dst_linesize,
                  (const uint8_t **)(frame->data), frame->linesize,
                  video_dec_ctx->pix_fmt, video_dec_ctx->width, video_dec_ctx->height);
    /* write to rawvideo file */
    fwrite(video_dst_data[0], 1, video_dst_bufsize, video_dst_file);

    AVPicture pic;
    avpicture_alloc( &pic, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, frame->width, frame->height);
    SwsContext *ctxt = sws_getContext(frame->width, frame->height, static_cast<AVPixelFormat>(frame->format),
        frame->width, frame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if ( NULL == ctxt )
    {
       //Log("failed to get sws context");
    }

    if ( 0 < sws_scale(ctxt, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, frame->height, pic.data, pic.linesize))
    {
        char szPic[256] = { 0 };
        sprintf( szPic, "decoded/%d.bmp", video_frame_count );
        FILE *pf = fopen(szPic,"w");
        if ( NULL != pf )
        {
            BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader = {0};
            bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
            bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
            bmpFileHeader.bfType = 0x4D42;
            bmpFileHeader.bfSize = sizeof(bmpFileHeader) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + pic.linesize[0] * frame->height;
            bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(bmpFileHeader) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            BITMAPINFOHEADER bmiHeader = { 0 };
            bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
            bmiHeader.biWidth = frame->width;
            bmiHeader.biHeight = 0 - frame->height;
            bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
            bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
            bmiHeader.biSizeImage = pic.linesize[0] * frame->height;
            bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
            bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
            bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
            bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
            fwrite( &bmpFileHeader, 1, sizeof(bmpFileHeader), pf );
            fwrite( &bmiHeader, 1, sizeof(bmiHeader), pf );
            fwrite( pic.data[0], 1, pic.linesize[0] * frame->height, pf );
            fclose( pf );
        }
    }
    // pic.data[0] now contains the image data in RGB format (3 bytes)
    // and pic.linesize[0] is the pitch of the data (ie. size of a row in memory, which can be larger than width*sizeof(pixel))


    avpicture_free(&pic);
    sws_freeContext(ctxt);
}
```

above only decode frame then convert this from to RGB24, then write a bitmap.
original video frame like this,
[image: original video]
but converted image,
[image: converted image]
is there missing some code or some code is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: A few things here: `1` wrong component order RGB vs BGR, `2` height in the file has to be positive, `3` line size in the file has to have minimal padding to 32-bit boundary even though SWS context stride could be larger. All together will get you correct BMP file.

Comment: thks, Roman R． But height can be negative, if here I give it positive value, the bitmap will be reversed image; BTW, image dimension is 1280 x 760, so it is 32-bit aligned; I also tried BGR24, same result.

Comment: The code is about right, so there is something wrong on runtime. For example, SWS context might be 1288 wide and not 1280 etc. This is OK for processing but not for the file. Perhaps you could post a link to the file you are getting.

Comment: I used source code from the linke

Comment: the source code is from 
http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/doc_2examples_2demuxing_8c-example.html
width should be 1280 rather than 1288, because 1280 * 3Bytes is 4Bytes aligned

Comment: You should make sure that `pic.linesize[0] == 3*frame->width`. Otherwise, the code will be invalid, you will need to write data line by line.

Comment: pic.linesize[0] == 3*frame->width

Comment: after calling function avpicture_alloc. following statement already is true( tested )
pic.linesize[0] == 3*frame->width

Comment: The problem was solved. I would like share it with you guys. The video decode is correct, but parameter passed in sws_getContext is wrong, while AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 should be AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 and one more thing need to be fixed that file should be open with "wb" instead of "w"

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> fwrite( pic.data[0], 1, pic.linesize[0] * frame->height, pf );
> ```

For an image of e.g. 1280x720, linesize is typically larger, e.g. 1312, so you'll be writing more data than image size if you write linesize*height. You want to write (in a loop) width pixels offset by linesize bytes:

```
uint8_t *ptr = pic.data[0];
for (int y = 0; y < frame->height; y++) {
    fwrite(ptr, 1, frame->width, pf);
    ptr += pic.linesize[0];
}
```

And then it should work correctly.

Answer (score -1):

maybe these codes can help you. these works good.

```
                int got_frame = 0;
                auto len = avcodec_decode_video2(m_avCodecContext
                    , m_avFrame
                    , &got_frame
                    , &avpkt);
                if (len < 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (got_frame /*&& !silentMode*/)
                {
                    //if (videoRenderer != nullptr)
                    {
                        if (frameSize == NULL)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        uint8_t *dst_data[4];
                        int dst_linesize[4];
                        int dst_w, dst_h;

                        int ret = 0;
                        if (1)// avcodec_alloc_frame()
                        {


                            auto stride = m_avFrame->linesize;
                            auto scan0 = m_avFrame->data;

                            SwsContext *scaleContext = sws_getContext(m_avCodecContext->width
                                , m_avCodecContext->height
                                , m_avCodecContext->pix_fmt
                                , m_avCodecContext->width
                                , m_avCodecContext->height
                                , PixelFormat::PIX_FMT_BGR24
                                , SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                            if (scaleContext == NULL)
                            {
                                //TODO: log error
                                return;
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                //*vb->signal = 1;
                                ret = avpicture_alloc(&m_dst_picture
                                    , PixelFormat::PIX_FMT_BGR24
                                    , m_avCodecContext->width
                                    , m_avCodecContext->height);
                                //                      AVFrame *picture_RGB;
                                //                      uint8_t *bufferRGB;
                                //                      picture_RGB = avcodec_alloc_frame();
                                //                      bufferRGB = (uint8_t*)malloc(720*576*(24/8)/*avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_RGB24, 720, 576)*/);
                                //                      avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)picture_RGB, bufferRGB, PIX_FMT_RGB24, 720, 576);
                                if (ret < 0)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                int retScale = sws_scale(scaleContext
                                    , scan0
                                    , stride
                                    , 0
                                    , m_avCodecContext->height
                                    , m_dst_picture.data //picture_RGB->data
                                    , m_dst_picture.linesize  //picture_RGB->linesize
                                    );
                                if (1)
                                {
                                    HWND hwnd = m_pParent->GetSafeHwnd();
                                    SetFocus(hwnd);
                                    CRect rc;
                                    m_pParent->GetClientRect(rc);
                                    CDC *cdc = m_pParent->GetDC();
                                    char* bitmap = (char*)m_dst_picture.data[0];
                                    //                          static unsigned int i = 0;
                                    //                          bmp_save(bitmap, m_avCodecContext->width, m_avCodecContext->height, i++);
                                    BITMAPINFO bmpinfo;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = m_avCodecContext->width;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -m_avCodecContext->height;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage =
                                        m_avCodecContext->width * m_avCodecContext->height * (24 / 8);
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 100;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 100;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
                                    bmpinfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
                                    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(cdc->GetSafeHdc(), &bmpinfo.bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, bitmap, &bmpinfo/*bi*/, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
                                    DrawBitmap(cdc, hBitmap, m_pParent);
                                    ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                                    ::DeleteObject(cdc->GetSafeHdc());
                                }
                                avpicture_free(&m_dst_picture);
                                sws_freeContext(scaleContext);
                            }
                            catch (int e)
                            {
                                sws_freeContext(scaleContext);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }





    void DrawBitmap(CDC *pDC, HBITMAP hbitmap,CWnd *wnd)
    {
        CBitmap *pBitmap = CBitmap::FromHandle(hbitmap);
        BITMAP bm;
        pBitmap -> GetBitmap(&bm);

        CDC MemDC;
        MemDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
        HGDIOBJ gob= MemDC.SelectObject(pBitmap);
        CRect rc;
        wnd->GetClientRect(rc);
        pDC->SetStretchBltMode( COLORONCOLOR);
        pDC->StretchBlt(0, 0,rc.Width(),rc.Height() , &MemDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);
        MemDC.SelectObject(gob);
        DeleteObject(pBitmap);
        DeleteObject(MemDC);
        DeleteObject(&bm);
        ReleaseDC(wnd->GetSafeHwnd(), MemDC);
    }



void initDecoder()
{
    m_avCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context();
    if (!m_avCodecContext)
    {
        //failed to allocate codec context
        Cleanup();
        return;
    }

    m_avCodecContext->flags = 0;

    uint8_t startCode[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //I thought for play live video you can comment these lines. 
    if (m_sProps != NULL)
    {
        //              USES_CONVERSION;
        //              ::MessageBox(NULL, A2T(sprops), TEXT("sprops"), MB_OK);
        unsigned spropCount;
        SPropRecord* spropRecords = parseSPropParameterSets(m_sProps, spropCount);
        try
        {
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < spropCount; ++i)
            {
                AddExtraData(startCode, sizeof(startCode));
                AddExtraData(spropRecords[i].sPropBytes, spropRecords[i].sPropLength);
            }
        }
        catch (void*)
        {
            //extradata exceeds size limit
            delete[] spropRecords;
            Cleanup();
            return;
        }
        delete[] spropRecords;

        m_avCodecContext->extradata = extraDataBuffer;
        m_avCodecContext->extradata_size = extraDataSize;
    }
    AddExtraData(startCode, sizeof(startCode));
    bInitEx = true;

    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    m_codecId = CODEC_ID_H264;
    m_avCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_codecId);
    if (m_avCodec == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (avcodec_open(m_avCodecContext, m_avCodec) < 0)
    {
        //failed to open codec
        Cleanup();
        return;
    }


    if (m_avCodecContext->codec_id == CODEC_ID_H264)
    {
        m_avCodecContext->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;
        //avCodecContext->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_SHOW_ALL;
    }
    m_avFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (!m_avFrame)
    {
        //failed to allocate frame
        Cleanup();
        return;
    }
}
```